# Eclipse 3.4 + Sonar

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, sonarqube, rad

First time I'm posting here. I've always used S.O. and finally decided to make an account so I can be part of this. 
Now, to the question. :)
Currently, I'm using RAD 7.5.4 (Eclipse 4.3) and I'm trying to install Sonar's plugin to my IDE but I keep getting errors while I try to install it from the IDE:

> Cannot complete the request.  See the details. Unsatisfied dependency:
>   [org.sonar.ide.eclipse.jdt.feature.feature.group
>   3.4.0.20140404-0949-RELEASE] requiredCapability: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu/org.eclipse.platform.feature.group/3.6.0
>   Unsatisfied dependency: [org.sonar.ide.eclipse.ui
>   3.4.0.20140404-0949-RELEASE] requiredCapability: osgi.bundle/org.eclipse.core.databinding.property/0.0.0 Unsatisfied
>   dependency: [org.sonar.ide.eclipse.ui 3.4.0.20140404-0949-RELEASE]
>   requiredCapability:
>   osgi.bundle/org.eclipse.core.databinding.property/0.0.0 Unsatisfied
>   dependency: [org.sonar.ide.eclipse.ui 3.4.0.20140404-0949-RELEASE]
>   requiredCapability:
>   osgi.bundle/org.eclipse.core.databinding.property/0.0.0 Unsatisfied
>   dependency: [org.sonar.ide.eclipse.jdt 3.4.0.20140404-0949-RELEASE]
>   requiredCapability: osgi.bundle/org.sonar.ide.eclipse.ui/0.0.0
>   Unsatisfied dependency:
>   [org.sonar.ide.eclipse.jdt.feature.feature.group
>   3.4.0.20140404-0949-RELEASE] requiredCapability: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu/org.sonar.ide.eclipse.jdt/[3.4.0.20140404-0949-RELEASE,3.4.0.20140404-0949-RELEASE]
>   Unsatisfied dependency:
>   [org.sonar.ide.eclipse.jdt.feature.feature.group
>   3.4.0.20140404-0949-RELEASE] requiredCapability: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu/org.eclipse.platform.feature.group/3.6.0
>   Unsatisfied dependency:
>   [org.sonar.ide.eclipse.jdt.feature.feature.group
>   3.4.0.20140404-0949-RELEASE] requiredCapability: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu/org.sonar.ide.eclipse.ui/[3.4.0.20140404-0949-RELEASE,3.4.0.20140404-0949-RELEASE]

From what I've looked, this is not possible since Sonar [doesn't give support](http://sonarqube.15.x6.nabble.com/Plugin-Sonar-for-Eclipse-3-4-td5009273.html) for Eclipse 4.3. Maybe I've skipped something here, so... is there any way I can get Sonar's plugin to work in my RAD? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not possible. As [the documentation specifies it](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Installing+SonarQube+in+Eclipse), only versions > 3.7 are supported.